# ngFor in columns with differents properties

Tags: angular

I have this code in a `.html` using angular

```html
    <div id="container">
     <div class="row triple" *ngFor="let j of jugadores">
      <div class="column-3 left">{{j.nombre}}</div>
      <div class="column-3 center">{{j.nombre}}</div>
      <div class="column-3 right">{{j.nombre}}</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I want differents name in the columns.
How can I make the `*ngFor` to do that?

**Sample structure of the objects in `jugadores`**
[image: sample structure of the objects in jugadores]

**Current result (in red the expected result)**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like first name, middle name and last name ?

Comment: are you trying to change the class as left/right/center according to j.nomre value

Comment: No. I have a lot of names..so in column left the first one....in column center the 2 one..in column right the 3 one....

Comment: Is `nombre` an array of names ? Also, it would be better if you share a sample structure of the objects in `jugadores`.

Comment: nombre its an array of names, yes

Comment: can you share your array or any sample of it?

Comment: the .json where im taking the dates is like in the image

Comment: And i put the .json data into a array like: [nombre:,dorsal:]...

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

If nombre is string and you want to show values in different column:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="row triple" *ngFor="let j of jugadores;let i=index">

        <div class="column-3 left" *ngIf="(i+1)%3 === 1">{{j.nombre}}</div>
        <div class="column-3 center" *ngIf="(i+1)%3 === 2">{{j.nombre}}</div>
        <div class="column-3 right" *ngIf="(i+1)%3 === 0">{{j.nombre}}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Or If you want to display fields of array in different columns:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="row triple" *ngFor="let j of jugadores">
        <div class="column-3 left" >{{j.nombre}}</div>
        <div class="column-3 center" >{{j.dorsal}}</div>
        <div class="column-3 right" >{{j._links}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine. It takes care of the classes based on index.

Comment: I have this error: ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Antonio Adán' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Im saving all of tha in a class Jugadores with nombre:string;

Comment: This can be because your 'j.nombre' is not array. It is of string type. NgFor is supported only on arrays

Comment: 1st option is for the case where 'j.nombre' is of array type and 2nd one is for displaying all fields of your object array

Comment: its a string, yes

Comment: can you share what is your expected output?

Comment: The second image

Comment: @RAZVANLISMANU Is this change helpful? Let me know whether it worked or not

Comment: What is the issue now @RAZVANLISMANU

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need a nested loop to iterate over the elements of `nombre`.
Example:

```js
<div id="container">
     <div class="row triple" *ngFor="let j of jugadores">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let name of j.nombre">
        <div class="column-3 left">{{name}}</div>
      </ng-container>
      <div class="sample">{{j.someOtherProperty}}</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

> You can use `ng-container` to avoid using a new html element just for
>   the loop.

Answer (score 1):

to iterate `jugadores` array

```
<div id="container" class="row">
  <div [class]="getClass(i)" *ngFor="let j of jugadores; let i = index">
    {{ j.nombre }}
  </div>
</div>
```

getClass function to get class of current `index`

```
// in component

  getClass(i){
    let className = 'col-4 ';
    switch(i%3){
      case 0: className += 'left'; break;
      case 1: className += 'center'; break;
      case 2: className += 'right'; break;
    }
    return className;
  }
```

working sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzefk3)